# Python regexp \n issue

Tags: python, regex, newline, linefeed, lf

This searched ok:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)\r\n(.+?)\r\n', 'aaa\r\r\nbbb\r\n').groups()
('aaa\r', 'bbb')
```

But when I replace one of three `b` to `\n` it not searched:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)\r\n(.+?)\r\n', 'aaa\r\r\nb\nc\r\n').groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

But I want to parse in second case:

```
('aaa\r', 'b\nc')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

```
import re
re.search(r'(.*?)\r\n(.+?)\r\n', 'aaa\r\r\nb\nc\r\n', flags=re.DOTALL).groups()
```

result:

```
('aaa\r', 'b\nc')
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes `.` not matched `\n` by default